# システムのフォントサイズの変化を監視したい

Tags: .net, wpf

システムのフォントサイズは SystemFonts.MessageFontSize で取得できるのですが、この値が変化したというイベントはどのようにしたら取得できるでしょうか。

XAMLから直接参照するならば DynamicResource で実現可能ですが、今回はコード内での利用を考えています。

#### 目的

システムのフォントサイズを元に、各種フォントサイズやアイコンサイズ、レイアウトを計算して追従させる

#### 環境

- .NET framework 4.8

Comment: この記事 [How to change the default font, font size and font style in Windows 10?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-change-the-default-font-font-size-and-font/5145b30f-b7c0-4961-836f-0259c06d533c), [Windows 10 のテキストのサイズを変更する](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4028566) の関連で、もしかしたらこちら [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged イベント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged?view=net-5.0) で分かるかもしれませんね。試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: DisplaySettingsChanged を試してみましたが、フォントサイズ変更ではこのイベントは発生しませんでした。

Comment: 或いはこの辺の [Windows...Font/Text Size...](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windowsfile-explorer-fonttext-size-settings-no/eecaaf81-d250-45ff-a9b8-4f99d614e033), [How to Change Text Size...](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/19768-change-icons-text-size-windows-10-a.html), [How to Change DPI Scaling...](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-change-dpi-scaling-level-displays-windows-10-a.html) 関連で、変更レジストリを特定して監視するとか？[RegNotifyChangeKeyValue function (winreg.h)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Formsの事例ですが、[SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged?view=netframework-4.8)イベントを使ってシステムフォントの変更を監視する方法が紹介されています。

- [Respond to Font Scheme Changes in a Windows Forms app | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-respond-to-font-scheme-changes-in-a-windows-forms-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

注意点として、このイベントはスタティックイベントなので、追加したイベントハンドラーはアプリケーションの破棄時に削除するようにしておかないとメモリリークします。

[System.Drawing.SystemFonts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemfonts?view=netframework-4.8)クラスおよび[System.Drawing.Font](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font?view=netframework-4.8)クラスはGDI+の.NETラッパーですが、フォントサイズなどの情報を取得するだけであればWPFからでも（System.Drawing.dll のアセンブリ参照を追加するだけで）使用できるはずです。

しかし、イベントを受けてコードビハインドで変更を反映するのではなく、XAMLで[System.Windows.SystemFonts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemfonts?view=netframework-4.8)を参照することを強く推奨します。

- [How to: Use SystemFonts - WPF .NET Framework | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-systemfonts?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

システムフォントサイズをそのまま使うのではなく、一定の倍率を乗じた値を利用したいなどの場合は、バインディングの際にコンバーターを挟めばよいだけです。

- [データ バインディングの概要 - WPF .NET Framework | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#data-conversion)

また、画面レイアウトはフォントサイズに依存しないように相対的に設計するべきです。